# Ragged hierarchies in Power Pivot

Tags: powerpivot

In Power BI, one can use the Hierarchy Slicer vis from AppSource to hide items that contain blank values:

[image: Hiding blanks in Hierarchy Slicer]

Is there a feature similar to that, but in Power Pivot? I want to hide the blank values, but I'm not to filter them, since filtering will affect the subtotals:

[image: Power Pivot with blank values]